# Aptana win7 64bit myeclipse plugin bug

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana

I installed `aptana eclipse` on  `myclipse(Version: 6.0.1 GA Build id: 6.0.1-GA-200710),pc(win7 64bit)`. I got the following error message when starting `myeclipse` every time.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mozilla.xpcom.Mozilla.getServiceManager(Mozilla.java:867)
    at com.aptana.ide.xul.FirefoxBrowser.createControl(FirefoxBrowser.java:341)
    at com.aptana.ide.server.portal.ui.MyAptanaEditor.createPartControl(MyAptanaEditor.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2739)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$13(WorkbenchPage.java:2643)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2595)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2590)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2574)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2565)
    at com.aptana.ide.server.portal.ui.MyAptanaEditor.open(MyAptanaEditor.java:112)
    at com.aptana.ide.intro.actions.StartPortalAction.openPortalEditor(StartPortalAction.java:82)
    at com.aptana.ide.intro.actions.StartPortalAction.openPortalEditor(StartPortalAction.java:73)
    at com.aptana.ide.intro.actions.ShowMyAptanaAction.run(ShowMyAptanaAction.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1148)
```

Comment: This looks like version 2 of Aptana. Can you try version 3?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the preview tabs that Aptana tends to create. You can try turning them off from Window > Preferences, then search for "preview" (or try Aptana > Editors > CSS > Preview) or similar, and turn off generation of preview files.

Also, Eclipse has issues with 64bit compatibility when running against Aptana and other plugins that use JNI, since the Firefox codebase and many other programs are not fully 64-bit compliant yet. I would suggest running Eclipse+friends as 32bit apps. Eclipse is heavy and all, but I don't see it needing >3gb of memory. If you do this, make sure your Java word size (32 or 64 bit) matches Eclipse's, or it will crash on startup.